# Get a conexión TCP

Tags: javascript

Hola no tengo mucha idea de programar y me han pedido que haga una petición `get` a través de `javascript` a `localhost:8010/log` que tiene una conexion `tcp.

He probado con el código de abajo pero nada (supongo que porque no es http) aunque si lo meto directamente en el navegador si que funciona

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "localhost:8010/log"
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    alert("OK");
}, function myError(response) {
    alert("FL");
});
```

Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 2):

Para hacer una petición `get`, puedes usar el siguiente código, sacado de [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$.get("localhost:8010/log", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

[Aquí tienes también otro ejemplo de como realizar la petición](https://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/funcion-get-jquery-ajax.html)

Para todo esto tienes que añadir la libreria de `jquery`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Me sale el error "ReferenceError: '$' is undefined"  ¿alguna idea de por qué?

Comment: has añadido la libreria de jquery? @Zass

Comment: si, perdon se me ha pasado que la tenía comentada. El problema es que  siempre me salta el fail sin embargo escribiendolo en el navegador va bien sabes por qué puede ser?